# Copy iPod Library file to iPhone app's folder, is it legal?

Tags: ios, app-store, ipod

Is it legal to copy songs from the iPod library to app's local folder, according to most recent App Store guideline?

My intention is to play songs with unity's audio source and do spectrum analysis at runtime. I can delete the songs from local folder once this process is finished. Is it OK?

Comment: Do you have to copy them?  Can you just read from the iPod library?

Comment: Unfortunately in order to use my spectrum analysis I have to copy them first.